# Python Requests get returns response code 401 for nse india website

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I use this program to get the json data from `https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY`
but since this morning it's not working as it returns `<Response [401]>`. The link loads fine on chrome though. Is there any way to fix this without using selenium ?

```
import json
import requests

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, '
                         'like Gecko) '
                         'Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36',
           'accept-language': 'en,gu;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8', 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'}

res = requests.get("https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY", headers=headers)
print(res)
```

Comment: I am getting "Resource Not Found" when I try to open [this](https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY) in chrome.

Comment: Works fine for me currently.

Comment: Same error for me. If I run the python script and then open the url in browser, it will show resource not found. Looks like NSE website is scanning for python script IPs and blocking them.

Answer (score 24):

Try this:

```
import requests

baseurl = "https://www.nseindia.com/"
url = f"https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY"
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, '
                         'like Gecko) '
                         'Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36',
           'accept-language': 'en,gu;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8', 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'}
session = requests.Session()
request = session.get(baseurl, headers=headers, timeout=5)
cookies = dict(request.cookies)
response = session.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=5, cookies=cookies)
print(response.json())
```

To access the NSE (api's) site multiple times then set `cookies` in each subsequent requests:

`response = session.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=5, cookies=cookies)`

Comment: Thank you so much VarunS2002 I have been strugling to get this solution from last two day and here I found!

Comment: If you're interested you can check my project out : https://github.com/VarunS2002/Python-NSE-Option-Chain-Analyzer

Comment: It means the world to me✌ Thank you

Comment: I tried the same approach but in Java. It works some times but still starts failing with 401 response for repeated polls.

Comment: Can you help me with my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77227650/getting-401-unauthorized-even-after-setting-browser-name-and-cookie-in-header?

Answer (score 0):

For performing and actions you first have to perform the login request call which will return you with session id .This session id will then be used in header section for next request to authenticate and return valid responce

Comment: Can you please share a code snippet of how that can be done in my program?

Comment: https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/login-page/create-session-login-token
try referring this link. It shows how you can get the session token and the same session token can be used in successive api calls to get authenticate and interact

Comment: NSE doesn't need a login

Answer (score 0):

Even I'm getting the same error from today morning. Earlier I used to face this issue only on servers hosted outside India. But now looks like they are trying to stop scraping altogether.

Really interested in finding a solution to this.

Also for the time being the [old website](https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?symbolCode=-10006&symbol=NIFTY&symbol=NIFTY&instrument=-&date=-&segmentLink=17&symbolCount=2&segmentLink=17) still seems to be working. I know it's not a permanent solution but I'm using that as a stop gap until I find a more permanent solution.

Comment: Yeah the old website works fine for now but it can stop anytime so gotta be prepared.

Answer (score 0):

I tried same thing with node js
please use node js ide [link here for online ide](https://replit.com/@larer50497/NSEINDIAAPI)
please review my code

```
const axios = require('axios');


let cookie;
let url_oc = "https://www.nseindia.com/option-chain"
let url = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY"
let headers = {
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)',
  'accept-language': 'en,gu;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8', 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'
}

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: url_oc,
  headers: headers,
  cookie: cookie ? cookie : ""
});



const getCookies = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await instance.get(url_oc);
    cookie = response.headers['set-cookie'].join();
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response.status === 403) {
      console.log("getCookies =========> error.status === 403");
      await getCookies()
    } else {
      console.log("getCookies =========> error");
    }
  }
}


const getAPIData = async () => {
  try {
    if (cookie) {
      const response = await instance.get(url);
      console.log(response.data.records.timestamp);
    }

  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
      console.log("getAPIData =========> error.status === 401");
      if (!cookie) {
        console.log("getAPIData =========> cookie not found");
        await getCookies()
      }
      await getAPIData()
    } else {
      console.log("getAPIData =========> error");
    }
  }
}



(async () => {
  setInterval(async () => {
    await getCookies()
  }, 5000);

  setInterval(async () => {
    await getAPIData()
  }, 3000);
})()
```

Comment: Abhi do you want code for node js or python.
I was tested above while that time it was working

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error with Java.
Solution is

- first make connection to https://nseindia.com.
- And then read the cookie returned by the server.
- Add the same cookie in your request.

Depending on which implementation you are using to make ssl calls, you will have to find appropriate methods to get and set cookies.
Dont know why NSE site has to look for a cookie when the data is publicly enabled.
Some extra technology applied by nse for sure!.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the 401 Unauthorized error when fetching JSON data from `https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY`, use a `requests.Session()` to maintain session state and handle cookies. First, make a request to the base URL to establish the session, then request the data using the same session. Here's the code:

```py
import requests

base_url = "https://www.nseindia.com/"
url = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY"
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept-Language': 'en,gu;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'
}

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.get(base_url, headers=headers)  # Establish session
    response = session.get(url, headers=headers)  # Fetch data
    if response.ok:
        data = response.json()
        print(data)
    else:
        print(f"Error: {response.status_code}")
```