# Unable To Fetch JSON Data From NSE

Tags: php

Don't know whether this is the appropriate forum or not for this question. Below mentioned code was working fine till day before yesterday. But now showing Resource Not Found. But, if I open another new tab and copy paste the URL, results are showing. And then again if I run the code, it's showing the desired result. Can anyone dealing with NSE data, guide me in this regard.

```
<html>
<head><title>test</title></head>
<body>
<?php
$url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/corporates-pit?index=equities&from_date=21-06-2020&to_date=21-09-2020&symbol=JUSTDIAL';
$response = getJSONData($url);
print_r($response);
function getJsonData($url){
print_r($url);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($result);
curl_close($ch);
$obj = json_decode($result,true);
return $obj;
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've tried it from a browser and code, both show *Resource not found*.  Do you have anything in the browser which may have logged into the site?

Comment: No. Nothing as such. If you keep https://www.nseindia.com/ opened in one tab and then try to open the url from another tab, it is working. Unable to understand what's happening. Might be cookies related stuffs.

Comment: Please check the below solution post by VarunS2002: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64044088/6834734

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSE has implemented time based cookies for API. If you try to access API data you won't get it.

Comment: thanks for the info.. i might have to figure out something different to automate reports...